# how to detect any browser back button click using java script or jquery?

Tags: button, browser, back

Could you please let me know how to detect any browser back button click using java script or jquery?

I am using the below :

```
if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
            window.history.pushState({page:this.href}, null, 'this.href');
            $(window).on('popstate', function() {
              event.preventDefault();
              $('#releaseLicenseApp').modal();
            });
        }
```

but it is not working in chrome and ie and firefox.

Comment: You can't. You're not allowed to interfere with the use of the back and forward buttons. Malware sites used to do this to prevent people from leaving their page.

Comment: @Barmar, I have one requirement in my project if I am in user creation page and if I click on back browser button then, I need to show 'Please save your changes before navigating to other page, if you continue then your unsaved data will be lost'. Then how to do this?

Comment: Why only the back button? Shouldn't they get that message if they try to close the page, too? Use the `beforeunload` handler.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in the comments, you only want to notify the user that there are unsaved changes when he tries to leave the page. This can be done using `onbeforeunload`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Please save your changes before navigating to other page, if you continue then your unsaved data will be lost.';
};
```

Comment: What my requirement is, if user clicks on browser back/forward button I want to show "Please save your changes before navigating to other page, if you continue then your unsaved data will be lost." with **Yes** and **No** button. If user clicks on Yes then, it will navigate to the backword/forward else it will stay on the same page

Comment: The snippet I posted will exactly do that and create a confirm box with two buttons.

Comment: No, it is shwoing **Leave this page** or **Stay on this page** as button. I want **Yes** and **No** as button.

Comment: You can't modify the default dialogue for `onbeforeunload`. You should match your text to the buttons action.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this on , it's working on chrome, ie  and firfox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.history.forward();
            function noBack()
            {
                window.history.forward();
            }
    </script>
    <body onLoad="noBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onUnload="">
```